# Firefox add-on SDK: Run content script in all open pages and any new ones

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

Let's say I have a simple content script, such as `window.alert("Hey there"); console.log("Content script")`.

I cannot figure out a way in the SDK that will make the script run on each open window and tab and also allow it to run on every new one.

Using tabs, the script will run on all new opened windows and tabs but will ignore those that have already loaded:

```
require("sdk/tabs").on("ready", function(tab) {
  tab.attach({
  contentScript: 'window.alert("Hey there");'
  });
});
```

Using pagemod with an include pattern of "*", the script will run only on windows and tabs with a non-blank URL:

```
require('sdk/page-mod').PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: "ready",
  contentScript: 'window.alert("AAAAAAAAA");'
});
```

I'm probably missing something simple that will allow me to implement this correctly. What is the right way to call a content script on all open and new pages?

Answer (score 0):

The `attachTo` property is what you are looking for.

```
require('sdk/page-mod').PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: "ready",
  contentScript: 'window.alert("AAAAAAAAA");',
  attachTo: ['existing', 'top', 'frame'] 
});
```

The content script in the sample will be injected into

- existing tabs
- top level tabs (including those that will be opened in the future)
- iframes inside any of the above tab types

**Mozilla Developer docs**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod%28options%29

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't work on blank tabs. For example, when you run the code with `cfx run`, you get a new blank Firefox window. I expect the content script to run in this new window. Also, I think you mean "top" instead of "new".

Comment: This is part of the solution, but the other part is working around the fact that * does not match a blank URL.

Comment: @aosdict Try `include:["*", "about:newtab"]`

Comment: Hmm. That fires the alert on the initial window the browser opens, but not any subsequently opened windows or tabs. Why isn't about:newtab (or any other about: page) matched by *?

Comment: It may be because `about` pages are local pages. Check out the docs for matching local pages: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/util_match-pattern

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run content script in about:blank and about:newtab,try to change tab url to upper case and reload tab.
about:blank and about:Blank are same page. and content script can run in about:Blank.

```
tabs.on(
    'ready',function(tab) {
        // if tab url is about:blank, change url to 'about:Blank', and reload when tab ready.
        if(Boolean(tab.url.match(/^about\:blank$/))){
            tab.url = 'about:Blank'
            tab.reload()
        }
        // run content script in about:Blank and about:NewTab
        else if(Boolean(tab.url.match(/^about\:(?:Blank|NewTab)$/))){
            var worker = tab.attach(
                {
                    contentScript:'console.log("run content script in '+tab.url+'")'
                }
            )
        }
    }
)

tabs.on(
    'open',function(tab) {
        // if tab url is about:newtab, change url to 'about:NewTab', and reload when tab open.
        if(Boolean(tab.url.match(/^about\:newtab$/))){
            tab.url = 'about:NewTab'
            tab.reload()
        }
    }
)
```